# Can anybody explain how this query works?

Tags: oracle

This is a SQL query to find the Nth highest salary of employees:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp t
WHERE 1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sal)
           FROM emp t2
           WHERE t2.sal > t.sal)
```

I don't know how it returns the result. If you put 1 in the `WHERE` clause, it will return the second highest, and for 2 the 3rd highest salary, and so on.

Please explain the query as I am unsure.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you working with? You've tagged both Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @Diado, while it's a wrong habit to tag multiple rbms's, does it really matter in this case?

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: @Diado I am just asking for the logic which will be same  in every RDBMS, so I don't think it will be a problem. This query will work in every RDBMS.

Comment: @PrakharDubey In that case you really should only use the tag `sql` without any product tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start by saying a better way to write the query is:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) as seqnum
      from emp e
     ) e
where seqnum = 2;
```

What is your query doing?  Go step-by-step:

- The outer query is doing a comparison for every row in `emp`.
- The comparison counts the number of distinct salaries that are larger than the salary in the row.
- The row is kept if there is exactly 1 salary that is larger.

In other words, this is keeping all rows that have the second largest salary.  `dense_rank()` is a much saner way to write the query (and it has better performance too).